# Getting error while collection has no data using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am getting an array length of `1` even if my MongoDB collection is blank. I am using PHP and MongoDB.

code :

```
$listdata=$db->kf_poll_master->find();

 echo (count($listdata));exit;
```

Here my collection: `kf_poll_master` has no data still the array length is showing `1` in echo where it should come as 0.

Comment: Try `var_dump($listdata)` it is like nuclear bomb in PHP.

Comment: @RohanKumar : I did as per you but it gave me this `object(MongoCursor)#7 (0) { }` output. I also did like this `print_r($listdata)` and it gave me this `MongoCursor Object ( )` as poupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MongoCollection::find()` does not return a PHP array, but an object of class [`MongoCursor`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php). You cannot use the native PHP count().

You should rather do :

```
echo $listdata->count();
```

Alternatively, you can convert the MongoCursor, which is an [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), to an array using [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php).